# Jmeter: How to get combined thread count from multiple jmeter slaves

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using jmeter distributed environment and distributing load on multiple slave machine. 
I am running `jmeter -g <csv file> -o <output folder>` command to get html report from output csv file.

In report `Time Vs Threads` graph shows only one slave machines thread count instead of combined thread count on x axis.

e.g. if my slave 1 and slave 2 running 10 thread each but generated graph shows 10 number of active thread on X axis but it should be 20.

Answer (score 0):

Try "**KPI vs KPI Graphs**" plugin. You can install it using plugins manager.